# Alternatives to validator.nu gem for ruby HTML5 validation

Tags: ruby, validation, rubygems

The validator.nu gem throws YAJL deprecation warnings and occasionally fails completely citing issues with the HTTPStream. Are there any stable ruby gems that will validate HTML5 documents?

e.g.

```
req1.9.2p320 :001 > require 'validator.nu'
DEPRECATION WARNING: Yajl::HttpStream is going to be removed in 2.0
DEPRECATION WARNING: Yajl's Gzip support is going to be removed in 2.0
DEPRECATION WARNING: Yajl's Deflate support is going to be removed in 2.0
=> true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `living-validator` gem does away with the `YAJL` dependency in favor of `HTTParty` and `JSON`. The github project is here: https://github.com/DynamiX-Web-Design/living-validator. It is also compatible with hosting your own living validator instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try my new HTML validation gem, html_validation. It's a rewrite/rebranding of another one I had done that people weren't finding, so it is based on some fairly well tested code. It runs locally, not through a web api. It uses HTML Tidy, put out by W3C.

https://github.com/ericbeland/html_validation